# Check drivers from Ubuntu

Tags: usb

is there a way I can check what model my drivers are from ubuntu?

I need to see what model my LAN USB adapter is.. But when I open Disk Utility all I see is my harddrive and a flash drive I've inserted.. Where can I go deeper and see my monitor model, my graphic card, all usb plugged in (like keyboard, mouse, internet) etc. ??
Thanks a lot

Comment: Try out `lsusb` command at terminal and see what is the description that you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo lshw
```

Should give you this info. If you want a better display, you can use `sudo lshw -html > file_of_your_choice.html` and open the file with your browser